# How to compile your CSS/JS and keep sprockets from concatenating the files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So we have an app made with rails that we are we are deploying to Heroku. We have been having very odd CSS, JS issues on the heroku build of our app. The CSS and JS are being put into one file when compiled. Is there any way to keep sprockets from concatenating my CSS and maybe even JS files, but still compile? Thanks

> Sprockets concatenates all JavaScript files into one master .js file
>   and all CSS files into one master .css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can individually compile your assets by

1) Adding each individual file to you the `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` array

2) Referencing each JS/CSS file with a `javascript_include_tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag`

3) Removing the sprocket references in you `application.js` & `application.css` files

Ultimately, you'll be going against best practice of providing a single, larger, JS/CSS files (slower load time), and this will be more difficult to maintain.

Alternatively, I'd suggest you sort out the issues you mentioned by correcting your load order within your `application.js/css` files such that they can be concatenated correctly without errors.

Comment: so you are saying we should add all our assets file in assets.rb under an array of  `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` , But, does not these assets files automatically added here..?I mean we dont have to add the assets file manually here. Wouldn't they come here automatically by running some command..If i am wrong please let me know. Thank You.